# Creating a GSI in DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, nosql

How do you create a GSI in the GUI of DynamoDB.  I see the primary key (which is the hash) and I assume the sort key in the GUI is the range?

Is the GSI creation process in the Create Indexes section?

Comment: Yes, you're in the right spot. Create Indexes is for creating GSIs and LSIs

Comment: Thanks for that +1 for the help